# Why is my audio autopaused? (READ OUTPUT)

Tags: discord, discord.js, ytdl

I want to reproduce a audio in my discord bot with a get request "control"

The bot join to the voice channel but didnt play nothing

Im using:
discord.js
@discordjs/voice
ytdl-core-discord
express

```
app.get('/test', async (req, res) => {
    const url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0DTyB7o_6HU";
    const channelId = "759867160859377688";

    try {
        const channel = await bot.channels.fetch(channelId);

        // Check if the channel is a voice channel
        if (!(channel instanceof VoiceChannel)) {
            res.status(400).json({ message: 'El canal proporcionado no es un canal de voz' });
            return;
        }
        // Connect to the voice channel
        const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: channel.id,
            guildId: channel.guild.id,
            adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
        });

        // // Create an audio player and resource
        const audioPlayer = createAudioPlayer();
        const audioResource = createAudioResource(await ytdl(url), { inlineVolume: true, highWaterMark: 1 << 25 });
        audioResource.volume.setVolume(1);

        // Play the audio
        audioPlayer.play(audioResource);
        connection.subscribe(audioPlayer);

        audioPlayer.on('stateChange', (oldState, newState) => {
            console.log(`Status: ${oldState.status} -> ${newState.status}`);
        });

        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Todo ok' });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }
});
```

OUTPUT:
Server on: https://**********************
Bot connected as ***********
Status: buffering -> playing
Status: playing -> autopaused